# In Gtk#, how can I pass an object reference in drag/drop?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, gtk, gtk#

From reading the documentation, it seems like you must send an array of bytes as the data. That makes sense for cross-program interoperability, but I just want to exchange data within my application. Is it possible to pass an object reference as the data?

Comment: From reading the docs, I don't think that's possible. A workaround is to use a dictionary to store "pointers" and their values.

Comment: You should post that as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Johannes Sasongko's comment:

> From reading the docs, I don't think that's possible. A workaround is to use a dictionary to store "pointers" and their values.